# How can I make shell aliases available when shelling out from Vim?

Tags: shell, vim, environment-variables, alias

In my `.zshrc`, I declare some aliases. Eg, `which dbstart` shows the contents of that alias.

If I open vim from that shell, it is a child process. In Vim, I can run shell commands with `:! some_command`. If I do `:! echo $0` to see what shell Vim is using, it outputs '/bin/zsh'. However, my aliases are unavailable there.

**How can I make my normal shell alises available when I shell out from Vim?**

Two ideas:

- Somehow `EXPORT` the aliases from the original shell, to its child process `vim`, and again to its shell child process
- Configure Vim to read my `.zshrc` when creating its subshells

Comment: include your `.zshrc` into .profile (which seems to be use by `vim`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Old question, but the cleanest solution for vim in zsh was to add the alias to `~/.zshenv`, the file that zsh loads for all shells, login, interactive, or otherwise. This avoids starting vim or zsh with flags and any possible problems with that.

There's a nice explanation of `~/.zshenv` vs `~/.zshrc` here: http://tanguy.ortolo.eu/blog/article25/shrc

Basically, zsh always sources `~/.zshenv`. Interactive shells source `~/.zshrc`, and login shells source `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zlogin`. Thus, an interactive login shell sources `~/.zshenv ~/.zprofile ~/.zlogin ~/.zlogin`, and a noninteractive, nonlogin shell like the one vim uses to run commands only sources `~/.zshenv`.

Comment: This is not a link-only answer, but it would be best if you inlined the explanation of the difference from the link; that way everyone can benefit from the explanation here and we are safe from linkrot.

Comment: Updated my answer with the main points from the link.

Comment: This worked exponentially better for me than the other answers. When I added for vim to start an interactive shell, it suspended immediately. When I use the .zshenv file (which I previously didn't know existed), I got my aliases back!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this works for zsh:

- Ensure that `$ZDOTDIR=` the directory where `.zshrc` is located. Eg, `export ZDOTDIR=$HOME`
- In `.vimrc`, `set shell=zsh\ -i` or `set shellcmdflag+=i` for the same effect.

The `-i` is because, when started in interactive mode, zshell loads `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`. See `man zsh` and search for `$ZDOTDIR` for details.

Comment: Hmmm, this creates a weird issue for me: copying to the system clipboard like `"+y` now suspends Vim! http://superuser.com/questions/712245/why-is-vim-suspended-when-i-copy-to-system-clipboard-if-my-shell-is-interactive

Comment: My vim becomes suspended as soon as I open it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you're in `vim` and you use the `:!some_command` it's using whatever shell is defined by the environment variable `$SHELL`.

This is configurable, so you could change by overriding the `$SHELL` behavior in your `$HOME/.vimrc` file to use `zsh` instead.

```
:set shell
shell=/bin/bash
:set shell=zsh\ -i
```

*Or in your `.vimrc` using 1 of these 2 lines*

```
 set shell=/bin/bash\ -i
 set shell=/bin/zsh\ -i
```

#### Vim help

See `:help shell` from within `vim` for more info.

```
:!{cmd}                 Execute {cmd} with the shell.  See also the 'shell'
                        and 'shelltype' option.
                        Any '!' in {cmd} is replaced with the previous
                        external command (see also 'cpoptions').  But not when
                        there is a backslash before the '!', then that
                        backslash is removed.  Example: ":!ls" followed by
                        ":!echo ! \! \\!" executes "echo ls ! \!".
                        After the command has been executed, the timestamp of
                        the current file is checked timestamp.
```

Comment: No, as I said: "If I do :! echo $0 to see what shell Vim is using, it outputs '/bin/zsh'"

Comment: @NathanLong - no I think that's misleading you, see my updates.

Comment: @slm vim pulls the value from `$SHELL`. So your shell is `/bin/bash`. If my shell is `/bin/zsh`, thats what it'll use.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `shell=/usr/bin/zsh\ -l` in `.vimrc` solved my problem

Note:

I'm using: linux mint 17.1

Comment: using ubuntu 14.04 this doesn't work for me